# Bulk photo upload to firebase storage in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-storage

In the app, user is able to select multiple photos, then, when user presses a button, all selected photos must be uploaded. During upload, a loader screen must be displayed, for that reason, I keep a state with array of user selected `photos`, and `isUploading` properties.
The problem is with uploading multiple photos, I need to retrieve urls of uploaded photos, and when all done, let user know about the results.
How can I accomplish that? My code so far:

```
//Method returns a URL of uploaded photo
  async uploadPhoto(photo) {
    const photoName = photo.substring(photo.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    const response = await fetch(photo);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("photos/" + photoName);
    const a = await ref.put(blob).then((snapshot) => {
      return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    }).catch(error => console.log("Error in async uploadPhoto", error))
    return a;
  }

//Method to bulk upload photos and get array of URLs 
  async uploadPhotos(photos) {
    let urls =  photos.map((photo) => {
      return this.uploadPhoto(photo.uri);
    })
    return urls;
  }
```

When I call `uploadPhotos(this.state.photos)` it returns me an array promises, how can I get an array of URLs from the method?

Comment: Maybe you should try return await uploadPhoto(photo.uri);